# Using models correctly in partial razor views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following controller:

```
public class WelcomeController
{
        private IWelcomeService _service;

        public WelcomeController(IWelcomeService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        public override ActionResult Index()
        {
            WelcomeIndexViewModel viewModel = new WelcomeIndexViewModel();
            viewModel.LatestNewsArticles = _service.GetLatestNewsArticles();
            return View(viewModel);
        }
}
```

And the following is the view model:

```
public class WelcomeIndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<LatestNewsArticle> LatestNewsArticles { get; set; }
}
```

The view model is populated by a service which populates the LatestNewsArticles property in the WelcomeIndexViewModel.

The following is the code for the view:

```
@model WelcomeIndexViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Welcome";
 }
 <main class="main" role="main">
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <div class=“news col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                @Html.Partial(“LatestNews", Model)
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </main>
```

And the following is the LatestNews partial view:

```
@model LatestNewsViewModel
<div class="latest-news">
    @foreach (LatestNewsArticle n in Model.LatestNewsArticles)
    {
        <h3><a href="@n.NewsArticleUrl" title="@n.Title">@n.Title</a></h3>
        <span class="featured-image">
            <img src="@FeaturedImageUrl" alt="@FeaturedImageAltText">
        </span>
        <p>@n.Summary</p>
    }
</div>
```

The `@model LatestNewsViewModel` is breaking the view because the model passed to it is not a LatestNewsViewModel.

If I remove the `@model LatestNewsViewModel` then I won't get a compile error on build if the model passed does not contain the right properties.

The `WelcomeIndexViewModel` does actually contain the property `LatestNewsArticles` but because it is not of the right type I get a compile error.

I'm not sure if it is a good practise to include a model in a property of another model but I guess this would work, however I'm really wondering what the right solution is in this scenario?

Comment: The model in the partial needs to be `@model WelcomeIndexViewModel` or you need to put the `foreach` loop in the main view and pass each `LatestNewsArticle` to the `@Html.Partial()`

Comment: The LatestNewsView is going to be used  on more than just the Welcome page so I can't require a model of WelcomeIndexViewModel.

Comment: Then the `foreach` loop needs to be in the main view, not the partial, but in any case you would be better off using a `DisplayTemplate` for typeof `LatestNewsArticle`

Comment: I don't want the foreach in the main view because the idea is that when the template changes the change applies across all pages displaying the latest news.

Comment: Stephen's right.  Using a `DisplayTemplate` is a better solution.  With that, you won't even have a loop - the template would be invoked for every item in the collection automatically.

Comment: That is exactly why you need to use a `DisplayTempate` (or put the `foreach` loop in the main view)! The template (or partial) is based on typeof `LatestNewsArticle`. If you ever decide to change or add another property to `LatestNewsArticle` then it will be updated in all views

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you show an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing typeof `WelcomeIndexViewModel` to the partial, but specifying that the partial accept type of `LatestNewsViewModel` which would throw an exception.

Then in the partial you attempt to loop through a property of `LatestNewsArticle` named `LatestNewsArticles` (which I suspect does not exist).

The best approach is to use a `DisplayTemplate` for typeof `LatestNewsArticle`.

In `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/LatestNewsArticle.cshtml`:

```
@model yourAssembly.LatestNewsArticle

<h3>
    <a href="@Model.NewsArticleUrl" title="@Model.Title">@Model.Title</a>
</h3>
<span class="featured-image">
    <img src="@Model.FeaturedImageUrl" alt="@Model.FeaturedImageAltText">
</span>
<p>@Model.Summary</p>
```

And then in the main view:

```
@model WelcomeIndexViewModel

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.LatestNewsArticles)
```

Note that `@Html.DisplayFor()` accepts both a single object `T` and `IEnumerable<T>`.

You can also place the file in `/Views/ControllerName/DisplayTemplates/LatestNewsArticle.cshtml` if you want the template for `LatestNewsArticle` to be specific to one controller.

Comment: Can the people down-voting this please explain why?

Comment: @Bonner, Who knows? I assumed it was a revenge vote but the answer by Chase would also have worked for you and it was down voted as well!

Comment: I accepted this answer as it is cleaner, the answer by chase requires a type hint in order to work so his example is almost right, that's probably why it was down voted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your partials like this:

```
@model WelcomeIndexViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Welcome";
 }
 <main class="main" role="main">
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="news col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                @Html.Partial("LatestNews", (object) Model.LatestNewsArticles)
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </main>
```

And then...

```
@model IEnumerable<LatestNewsArticle>
<div class="latest-news">
    @foreach (LatestNewsArticle n in Model)
    {
        <h3><a href="@n.NewsArticleUrl" title="@n.Title">@n.Title</a></h3>
        <span class="featured-image">
            <img src="@n.FeaturedImageUrl" alt="@n.FeaturedImageAltText" />
        </span>
        <p>@n.Summary</p>
    }
</div>
```

Also a good practice to use 
[**Display and Editor Templates**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/672591/Exploring-Display-and-Editor-Templates-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: simply because yours is the same as mine, and I have -- ;p

Comment: Yep, why you wrote the same?

Comment: I was writing and editing at the same time as you were! Hey, great minds think alike xD

Answer (score -2):

Use Model.LatestNewsArticles :)
See bold below:

```
@model WelcomeIndexViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Welcome";
 }
 <main class="main" role="main">
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <div class=“news col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                @Html.Partial(“LatestNews", Model**.LatestNewsArticles**)
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </main>
```

Oh, and use an IEnumerable in your partial view then:

```
@model IEnumerable<LatestNewsViewModel>
<div class="latest-news">
    @foreach (LatestNewsArticle n in Model)
    {
        <h3><a href="@n.NewsArticleUrl" title="@n.Title">@n.Title</a></h3>
        <span class="featured-image">
            <img src="@FeaturedImageUrl" alt="@FeaturedImageAltText">
        </span>
        <p>@n.Summary</p>
    }
</div>
```